# Impact of Air Conditioner on plywood

Tags: wood, air-conditioning, plywood, humidity, hardwood

I am going to set up a cupboard on a room which has AC.

I'm wondering what would be the effect of running an AC on 22 degree Celsius(Normal room temperature would be 30 to 35 degree depending on the season)

I know AC leads to change in humidity in the room and also I know when the temperature and humidity changes wood usually contracts or expands.

I'm wondering what would the effect of this on Hardwood ply.

There's Moisture Resistant ply but it's on expensive side.

I'd like some insights on this.

Comment: If it is a new piece, just got it from somewhere not AC, then should let be for a week or two in AC.  After two weeks can cut/make/paint cupboard and should be okay.  Doing it the day you buy it is when problems can happen.

Comment: You mean to say we should not cut the plywood the day we buy ..something new I'm hearing

Comment: Cutting is probably okay, but the wood should get used to the new place before being put together and/or painted.  Think every wood flooring you buy says to leave it in the room for a week or two before putting down on the floor.

Comment: The house is being constructed so AC can be moved in after the set up only

Comment: "*Acclimation* times vary by species and product, but a rule of thumb is to acclimate wood floor products for **at least three days**. You're trying to reach an *equilibrium between the moisture content of the wood materials and the air* where the product is being installed." - that's more for flooring where there's a billion butt joints. Also gives it time to warp or buckle if it's going to, and you discard those. Cabinet grade plywood? meh. Even w/o being inside an envelope yet, a few days in your air and it should be fine.

Comment: The problem is when you have forced air heat with a humidifier left at 50% and your wood casement windows start to sweat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is not much difference in the products.
Is the humidity an issue, when used with AC?
No, AC removes humidity, so any plywood would be less affected by moisture.

Plywood is cured with a temperature activated glue that is applied on all the layers of the core.
I worked for a leading plywood producer in the Pacific Northwest the main difference is the quality of the materials used. Marine grade used the same glue as the shop grade the difference was in marine grade the core and exterior sheets had no voids or knots the space between core pieces was tight, where shop grade may have a 1/4” or greater between core pieces and they may have knot holes (the knot holes in marine grade were plugged with a football shaped plug)
The hardwood faced product also used plugged core.

So do you need a moisture resistant plywood when using AC ? NO
There is less moisture in the air.